# Headless Browser: Audio Output to Pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, google-chrome, alsa

I'm trying to run a headless browser on an EC2/Ubuntu 20.04 instance and then output the resulting audio stream to the default Pulseaudio sink (which is then picked up by DarkIce/Icecast). I'm only wanting to run a single webpage (mine, hosted on a different server, requiring jQuery & Howler.js), and the resulting browser/stream has to remain open 24/7.

I've managed to get an audio file on the instance to play to Icecast (using ogg123), so ogg123>Pulseaudio>Darkice>Icecast2 works. I've created a default sink as below

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=radio
pacmd update-sink-proplist radio device.description=radio
pacmd set-default-sink radio
```

and  made Pulseaudio the default driver by creating ~/.asoundrc to include

```
pcm.default pulse
ctl.default pulse
```

I'm not sure what the correct approach is to get the browser to play nicely. I've tried (both google-chome and chromium) pointing directly to both an audio file and a page with js that plays audio (with the intention of eventually running it in Screen), both of which appear to find the content, neither approach plays any audio. For example,

```
 google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --user-data-dir=/home/ubuntu/chromeUser --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-software-rasterizer --enable-logging=stderr --v=1  https://domain.name/stream.html
```

generates the following

```
[0608/102421.257217:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 1
[0608/102421.258656:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 1
[0608/102421.258861:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(217)] ZygoteMain: initializing 0 fork delegates
[0608/102421.259318:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(217)] ZygoteMain: initializing 0 fork delegates
[0608/102421.271947:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(118)] Could not get the download directory.
[0608/102421.280120:VERBOSE1:breakpad_linux.cc(2071)] Non Browser crash dumping enabled for: gpu-process
[0608/102421.283276:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[0608/102421.286107:VERBOSE1:breakpad_linux.cc(2071)] Non Browser crash dumping enabled for: renderer
[0608/102421.288099:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(69)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: gpu-process.
[0608/102421.293815:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(69)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: renderer.
[0608/102421.303930:VERBOSE1:device_data_manager_x11.cc(216)] X Input extension not available
[0608/102421.356750:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(852)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[0608/102421.357514:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(852)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[0608/102421.359494:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://domain.name/stream.html
[0608/102421.411474:VERBOSE1:document.cc(3974)] Document::DispatchUnloadEvents() URL = <null>
[0608/102421.411727:VERBOSE1:document.cc(4054)] Actually dispatching an UnloadEvent: URL = <null>
[0608/102421.421675:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: /path/to/jquery.min.js
[0608/102421.424968:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: /path/to/jquery-ui.min.js
[0608/102421.429480:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: /path/to/howler.min.js
```

Is this the right approach to get this to work (and, if so, why doesn't it?), or should I be using Selenium/Puppeteer/something else?

Thanks, Chris

[aside: I've tried a [number of things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501093/passthrough-is-not-supported-gl-is-disabled) to try to remove the "Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader" error, without success, although it doesn't appear to prevent the browser from accessing the page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by running Puppeteer, rather than trying to wrangle Chromium from the command line. I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105376/3004316) to (hopefully) keep Puppeteer open with the following args to get the audio to start automatically.

```
 this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: true,
     ignoreDefaultArgs: [
         "--mute-audio",
     ],
     args: [
         "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required",
     ],
  });
```

After setting up the default sink in PulseAudio and adding ~/.ascoundrc (as above), it all works (sink audio picked up by DarkIce > IceCast > broadcast). I'll likely use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) to oversee Puppeteer, but for now it's a working solution.